# AngularJS remove items from array compared by id

Tags: javascript, angularjs, comparison

I want to remove from an array of items, a specific list of items. For instance, having an array of persons, I want to remove a couple of persons, compared by id. Or more generic, to specify property of comparison. Has angular already implemented something for this? I don't want to parse each array to compare each person from first array with each person from second array. Thanks.

This is what I tried:

```
var filteredUsers= self.users;
            angular.forEach(timekeepedUsers, function (user) {
                filteredUsers.splice(user, 1);
            });
            return filteredUsers;
```

Comment: Please share some code snippet of what you have tried

Comment: I just added, but this doesn't work properly. I am thinking to create a custom directive, but wondering if there isn't something build in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use standard JavaScript function to filter your array. Look at:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display that filtered array of "users", you can keep the array intact but just display the users you want by writing your own custom filter.

For the customfilter function in the controller, it is similar to callback where you can accept or reject an element of array by returning true or false respectively.

But if you want to filter the array for reuse as @przemod said you can use a simple JavaScript function.